# Find all reports filtered by specific field and value

Tags: apex, reporting, metadata-api, metadata

How can I find all reports in my Salesforce instance where the report is filtered by a specific field and value.

We need to surface this data to management because they want to make adjustments to those specific reports.

Ex. I want to find all reports in our Salesforce that are filtered with the Case Status of "Open".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step would be to pull all your reports' metadata in VS Code with [sfdx](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_retrieve)

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Report`

Within that metadata, [report filters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_report.htm#ReportFilter) have a specific syntax

```
<filter>
    <criteriaItems>
        <column>AMOUNT</column>
        <operator>greaterThan</operator>
        <value>1000</value>
    </criteriaItems>
</filter>
```

In your case, you're looking for `Status` so you now search through the metadata you pulled to find the reports with those references.

In VS Code, you can search all (`CTRL + Shift + F`) and specify what type of files to include (`report-meta.xml`).

You can find a report you know has the filter and just copy the beginning part (with spacing/line breaks). I'd use something like the below to get all instance of using `Status` in the filter at all.

```
<filter>
        <criteriaItems>
            <column>STATUS</column>
```

However, if you need more specificity (equals `Open`), you can copy the whole block to search with

```
<filter>
    <criteriaItems>
        <column>STATUS</column>
        <columnToColumn>false</columnToColumn>
        <isUnlocked>true</isUnlocked>
        <operator>equals</operator>
        <value>Open</value>
    </criteriaItems>
    <language>en_US</language>
</filter>
```

However, any slight difference (filter is locked vs. unlocked) won't appear in your search results which is why I'd go for less specific - all depends on the # of reports you're dealing with.

[image]